# Is the function $ f(z):= \begin{cases} \gamma(h^{-1}(z)) & \text{ if } z\neq 1\\ \gamma(1)& \text{ if } z=1 \end{cases}$ continuous at $z=1$?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I'm reading the book: "Deimling Nonlinear Analysis" and I'm blocked on a proof, at page 30, when proving that the winding number is a special case of the topological degree.

In the proof is constructed the function $f $ as follows:

First, take a closed oriented curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$, then consider the homeomorphism $h: (0,1)\to \partial B_1(0): s\mapsto e^{2\pi i s}$.
The fact that $h$ is a homeomorphism is quite clear.
Then it's stated that the function $$ f(z):= \begin{cases} \gamma(h^{-1}(z)) & \text{ if } z\neq 1\\ \gamma(1)& \text{ if } z=1 \end{cases}$$

is continuous.
Now, I grasp intuitively why it should be true, and that's because $h$ "reaches" $z=1$ when $s$ goes to $0$ or to $1$, and $\gamma \to \gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$ in both cases.
But this clearly is not a proof since I can't just "see that the left limit is equal to the right limit" as if it were a real function.

Can anyone please help me? :)

[image]

Comment: $h$ is no homeomorphism. It is an open embedding with image $\partial B_1(0) \setminus \{1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$ then $\gamma$ induces a quotient function $$\overline{\gamma}:[0,1]/\{0,1\}\to\mathbb{C}$$
$$\overline{\gamma}([t])=\gamma(t)$$

On the other hand $h$ can be extended to $[0,1]$ as well,
$h(s)=exp(2\pi i s)$. And it also has $h(0)=h(1)$ property, and thus it induces a quotient map

$$\overline{h}:[0,1]/\{0,1\}\to \mathbb{C}$$
$$\overline{h}([t])=h(t)$$
as well. These two maps are well defined and continuous by the general properties of quotient topologies. Moreover $\overline{h}$ is a homeomorphism onto image. That's because $\overline{h}$ is injective and $[0,1]/\{0,1\}$ is compact.

Finally we define $f(z)=\overline{\gamma}(\overline{h}^{-1}(z))$. This gives us the same function as your original $f$, but it is straight forward that it is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

What the author does is a bit handwoven. He wants to associate to $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb C$ a map $f : S \to \mathbb C$, where $S$ is the unit circle.

The map $h : [0,1] \to S, h(s) = e^{2\pi i s}$, is a continuous surjection. Since $[0,1]$ is compact and $S$ is Hausdorff, it is closed map and hence a quotient map.

$h$ identifies the two points $0,1 \in [0,1]$ to the single point $1 \in S$ and maps $(0,1)$ bijectively (even homeomorphically, though we don't need it) onto $S \setminus \{1\}$. Since $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$, there exists a unique function $f : S \to \mathbb C$ such that $f \circ h = \gamma$. Just observe that $\gamma (h^{-1}(z))$ is single-valued for all $z \in S$, thus $\gamma (h^{-1}(z)) = \{f(z)\}$ with a unique $f(z) \in \mathbb C$. You can easily check that this function is precisely that defined by the author, but we don't need this explicit formula.

The universal property of quotient maps shows then that $f$ is continuous.

**Remark:** I am not sure what you know about general topology. If you do not know what a quotient map is, and what the above "universal property" is, then I would recommend to learn a bit about these are concepts because they are really important.